# Ordering by "post__in" doesn't result in the correct order

Tags: wordpress

After creating a flat array of post IDs, I want to display those posts through a custom query in the same order as in my array. [The doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) states that `post__in` will "Preserve post ID order given in the post__in array". Yet in my case it does not. Why?

Creation of my array of post IDs:

```
if (have_rows('cases')) :
  while (have_rows('cases')) : the_row();
    $array_cases[] = get_sub_field('case');
  endwhile;
endif;
print_r($array_cases);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
  [0] => 2959
  [1] => 919
  [2] => 914
  ...
)
```

WP_Query():

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'iw-project',
  'post__in' => $array_cases,
  'orderby' => 'post__in'
);
$query_cases = new WP_Query($args);
print_r($query_cases);
```

Result:

```
WP_Query Object
(
  ...
  [posts] => Array
    (
      [0] => WP_Post Object
        (
          [ID] => 2959
          ...
        )

      [1] => WP_Post Object
        (
          [ID] => 914
          ...
        )

      [2] => WP_Post Object
        (
          [ID] => 1974
          ...
        )
    )
)
```

The order in the resulting query result is wrong. The second and third posts should be 919 and 914, not 914 and 1974.

Below is the raw SQL of the WP_Query object:

```sql
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts  
JOIN wp_icl_translations t ON wp_posts.ID = t.element_id AND t.element_type = CONCAT('post_', wp_posts.post_type) 
WHERE 1=1 
AND wp_posts.ID IN (2959,919,914,1593,1583,1974,1649,993,675) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'iw-project' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled') 
AND ((t.language_code = 'en' AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'iw-project', 'iw-contact', 'iw-slide', 'iw-client')) OR wp_posts.post_type NOT IN ('post','page','iw-project','iw-contact','iw-slide','iw-client'))  
ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order, FIELD(wp_posts.ID, 2959, 919, 914, 1593, 1583, 1974, 1649, 993 ,675) 
LIMIT 0, 8
```

Comment: Can you confirm that post 919 is in your result array at all? Does post 919 have post type 'iw-project' and is it not deleted? I don't see 919 in your result at all. So maybe it simply doesn't get matched by your query conditions.

Comment: Good question. But yes it is, in 7th position. And it belongs indeed to the "iw-project" post type.

Comment: Can you try all the solutions posted by the accepted answer here and let me know if it works?
 https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/220014/wp-query-and-order-by-particular-specified-ids

Comment: I just tried installing wordpress to reproduce your problem but I could not reproduce it. My query is correctly preserving the order of posts from the `post__in` array (even without adding the `order` parameter). Can you please try getting the raw sql from your wp_query object? You can do this by printing out the request property like this: `print_r($query_cases->request)`. That should give you the raw SQL. Edit the SQL that you get into your question.

Comment: @KodosJohnson thanks, I edited my question and added the raw SQL

Comment: Take a look at the ORDER BY part of your SQL code. It does an order by wp_posts.menu_order BEFORE it uses the order specified by post__in. So the menu_order takes priority over the post__in order. It seems to be identical to the problem in the post I linked to in my earlier comment. Have you tried passing in a `'suppress_filters' => true,` option to see if that works?

Comment: You're my man @KodosJohnson! Both 'suppress_filters' => true and remove_all_actions('pre_get_posts'); made it work. Only either one of them didn't. Can you create an answer so I can accept it + bounty? Btw, why was it not working as per codex? Is that a bug?

Comment: I created an answer below. It was not working because a filter that overrides the order of the WP_Query class. This filter was probably created by your theme or a plugin. Wordpress allows theme and plugins to override the default order. So this not really a Wordpress bug. But you could say that it is a bug introduced by your theme or one of your plugins you installed.

Comment: Got it and thanks again :)

Answer (score 7):

If you look at the `WP_Query`-generated SQL code you provided, you should note this snippet that handles the order:

```sql
ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order, FIELD(wp_posts.ID, 2959,919,914,1593,1583,1974,1649,993,675)
```

What this means is that it is ordering by `wp_posts.menu_order` *before* it does the order based on post IDs in your array (`2959,919,914,...`). It looks like a `filter` is overriding the default order of `WP_Query` results. This could be caused by either a theme or plugin.

The solution is to prevent other filters from modifying your query by passing in the parameter `'suppress_filters' => true`. Also, you should call `remove_all_actions('pre_get_posts');` before your `WP_Query`. This should prevent any other filters from modifying your query.

Some credit for the solution goes to [this WP.SE answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/220089/101075) for a very similar question.